# Rails redirect loop in production, everything is fine in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am running into an issue with Rails where in production it generates an error in the log file, but nothing in the development mode:

```
I, [2019-10-16T12:02:16.953954 #11866]  INFO -- : [e5d5e3b6-2a9c-4d27-b1f3-2d5a1b76ce5a] Started GET "/" for 155.186.157.103 at 2019-10-16 12:02:16 -0500
I, [2019-10-16T12:02:16.955549 #11866]  INFO -- : [e5d5e3b6-2a9c-4d27-b1f3-2d5a1b76ce5a] Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
I, [2019-10-16T12:02:16.956733 #11866]  INFO -- : [e5d5e3b6-2a9c-4d27-b1f3-2d5a1b76ce5a]   Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
I, [2019-10-16T12:02:16.958443 #11866]  INFO -- : [e5d5e3b6-2a9c-4d27-b1f3-2d5a1b76ce5a]   Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.3ms)
I, [2019-10-16T12:02:16.958796 #11866]  INFO -- : [e5d5e3b6-2a9c-4d27-b1f3-2d5a1b76ce5a]   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
E, [2019-10-16T12:02:29.471353 #11866] ERROR -- : [2c2037b2-3b07-495d-b936-778c070e1ad7] undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
I, [2019-10-16T12:02:29.473147 #11866]  INFO -- : [2c2037b2-3b07-495d-b936-778c070e1ad7] Redirected to [redacted-for-stackoverflow]
I, [2019-10-16T12:02:29.473928 #11866]  INFO -- : [2c2037b2-3b07-495d-b936-778c070e1ad7] Completed 302 Found in 22438ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
E, [2019-10-16T12:02:39.225917 #11866] ERROR -- : [e5d5e3b6-2a9c-4d27-b1f3-2d5a1b76ce5a] undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
I, [2019-10-16T12:02:39.227867 #11866]  INFO -- : [e5d5e3b6-2a9c-4d27-b1f3-2d5a1b76ce5a] Redirected to [redacted-for-stackoverflow]
I, [2019-10-16T12:02:39.229075 #11866]  INFO -- : [e5d5e3b6-2a9c-4d27-b1f3-2d5a1b76ce5a] Completed 302 Found in 22273ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

However, if I load development mode, the login page comes up just fine. I can't figure out what could possibly be causing this error since the error isn't descriptive as to where the issue resides.

I ran across another post to temporarily change `config.consider_all_requests_local       = false` to `config.consider_all_requests_local       = true` in `config/environments/production.rb` but that hasn't changed anything. No additional information is being provided.

How can I trace down this issue that's only occurring in production?

I have literally replaced everything in `layouts/application.html.erb` to try pin pointing where the issue is, but no luck. I noticed that `rake assets:precompile` fails as well with the same error, so perhaps it has some kind of issue in there.

Comment: Can you set the rails environment to production on your development PC? Have you altered sessions/New in any way?

Comment: Getting the same error. Troubleshooting it locally as well to see what's up. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the contents of `devise/sessions/new.html.erb`

It seems you are attempting to access a hash by key  e.g. `my_hash[:my_key]`  but `my_hash` in nil

Comment: I just temporarily cleared out the entire `devise/sessions/new.html.erb` file and the error still shows up. Very weird.

Answer (score 0):

After troubleshooting this some more, it finally boiled down to a stylesheet ending in `.css` rather than `.css.scss` since it was loading some rails stuff. I only came across this because `rake assets:precompile` kept failing.